# Save bitmap converted to mat on Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap

I'm testing the consumption of memory ram with openCV. 
I want to convert a generated bitmap with the method `view.getDrawingCache()` to mat and save it with the OpenCV `imWrite` method. Using this result is empty file.

```
childView.buildDrawingCache();
mat=new Mat(childView.getMeasuredHeight(),width, CvType.CV_8U);  
Utils.bitmapToMat(Bitmap.createBitmap(childView.getDrawingCache()),mat);
MatOfInt matInt=new MatOfInt();
matInt.fromArray(Imgcodecs.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0);
Imgcodecs.imwrite(cacheFile.getPath() + "/" + name + ".png", image, matInt);
```

On the other hand if I save the `bitmap` in memory of the system and charge it with the `imRead()` method and save it with `imWrite()` if that generates the file correctly.

```
Bitmap bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(childView.getDrawingCache());
cacheFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();

MatOfInt matInt=new MatOfInt();
matInt.fromArray(Imgcodecs.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0);
Mat mat=Imgcodecs.imread(mapCacheViews.get(getFinalTweetAdapter().getItem(i).id))
Imgcodecs.imwrite(cacheFile.getPath() + "/" + name + ".png", mat, matInt);
```

If the generated bitmap exits the same in both cases, that the first is not    nothing and the second is saved perfectly? Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
Mat tmp = new Mat (avatar.getWidth(), avatar.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
Utils.bitmapToMat(avatar, tmp);
Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgcodecs.imwrite(cacheFile.getAbsolutePath(),tmp);
```

Adding this line     Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, CvType.CV_8UC1); work fine